# Can Erwin Forward Engineer a Physical model to generate T-SQL Table Creation scripts?

Tags: database-design, ddl

I never used ErWin, but I think it would be a shame if the DB Developers had to manually create all of the tables that have already been defined in a huge ErWin Physical model.

Can Erwin generate SQL Server specific DDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Erwin can generate MS SQL Server specific DDL.